# Добавление дополнительного скрипта в GWT страницу

Tags: gwt, javascript, java

Есть код:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Proverka.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="proverka/proverka.nocache.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1'></iframe>
    <noscript>
        <div>
  Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled
  in order for this application to display correctly.
        </div>
    </noscript>    
</body>
</html>
```

Куда нужно вставить строку, чтобы получить данные?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://api.wipmania.com/wip.js"></script>
```

Comment: Что значит получить данные? Почему нельзя просто вставить эту строку в head?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вы имеете ввиду такое:

```
ScriptElement e = Document.get().createScriptElement(); 
e.setSrc("http://api.wipmania.com/wip.js"); 
e.setType("text/javascript");
DOM.appendChild(RootPanel.get().getElement(), e.<Element>cast());
```

Comment: Вообще таким образом можно добавить скрипт. Но лучше вписывать скрипт-элементы непосредственно в html-файл. Потому что динамическое добавление скриптов блокируется многими популярными плагинами (например, noscript). В этом случае приложение просто не запуститься.

Comment: Всё намного хуже: некоторые браузеры (не будем показывать пальцем) имеют лимит на количество созданных скипт-элементов

Answer (score 1):

Вставить в любое место в head, после этого будет доступен объект WIPlocation где-угодно на сайте.